# How to differentiate this fraction $\frac{2}{x^2+3^3}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$\frac{2}{(x^2+3)^3}$.

I have ${dy}/{dx}$ x 2 x ${x^2+3^3}$ - 2 x ${dy}/{dx}$  x ${x^2+3^3}$ over $({x^2+3)^6}$

And then simplifying to $-12x^5 + 36x^2$  over $({x^2+3)^6}$

I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: Is the cube applied to the whole denominator?

Comment: Yes. I edited it.

Comment: Then the answer by @user115350 is the best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical approach:
$$\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)' = \frac{u'v - uv'}{v^2}$$ whereas $u$ and $v$ are functions in $x$.

So when we have

$$\frac{2}{x^2+3^3}$$
We have

$$u(x) = 2$$
$$v(x) = x^2+ 3^3$$

And from that it follows

$$u'(x) = 0$$
$$v'(x) = 2x$$

Using the above formula

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{2}{x^2+3^3}\right) = \frac{0 -2\cdot2x}{(x^2+3^3)^2} = \frac{-4x}{x^4+2\cdot 3^3 x^2 + 3^6} = \frac{-4x}{x^4+54x^2+729}$$

Comment: Shouldn't the power rule be included in the following step?

So, it's 0 times $x^2+3^3$ -2x times 3 times $x^2+3^2$ times $x^2$?

Comment: I applied the power rule correctly for $v(x) = x^2+3^3$. The power rule states that the derivative of a polyomial is $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^n\right) = nx^{n-1}$, which I used to come to the conclusion that $v'(x) = 2x$. Then I just substituted it into the quotient-rule formula, without taking any other derivatives. Additive constants vanish when diff'ing. This answer doesn't however reflect the current state of the question, since you changed $x^2+3^3$ to $(x^2+3)^3$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may apply
$$
\left( \frac1{f}\right)'=-\frac{f'}{f^2} \tag1
$$ with
$$
f(x)=x^2+3^3.
$$
Find $f'(x)$ then use $(1)$ and conclude with $\dfrac2{x^2+3^3}=2 \times \dfrac1{x^2+3^3}=2 \times \dfrac1{f}$.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't see how the formula equals that. Wouldn't the apotrophe just multiply to both the numerator and denominator without changing anything?

Comment: @user6050977 Applying what I mentioned above gives $\left( \frac2{x^2+3^3}\right)'=2 \times \left(-\frac{2x}{(x^2+3^3)^2}\right)$. Is it OK for you?

Comment: I've never been able to understand how formulas relate to the actual problems. I have dyscalculia.

Comment: Are you known to the chain rule and to negative powers? You can write $\frac{2}{x^2 + 3^2} = 2(x^2+3^2)^{-1}$. Now you can use the chain rule ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the quotient rule or the product rule. Let's use the **quotient rule** for this:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})=\frac{f'g-g'f}{g^2}$$

In your case we have: $f(x)=2 \implies f'(x)=0$ and $g(x)=x^2+3^3 \implies g'(x)=2x$

It follows:

$$\implies \frac{f'g-g'f}{g^2}=\frac{0\cdot (x^2+3^3)-2x\cdot2}{(x^2+3^3)^2}=\frac{-4x}{(x^2+3^3)^2}$$

The other approach would be to use the **product rule**:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)\cdot g(x))=f'g+g'f$$

In your case we have $$\frac{2}{x^2+3^3}=2(x^2+3^3)^{-1}$$

The corresponding functions and derivatives are: $f(x)=2 \implies f'(x)=0$ and $g(x)=(x^2+3^3)^{-1} \implies g'(x)=-2x(x^2+3^3)^{-2}$ (I used the chain rule here)

$$\implies f'g+g'f=0 \cdot (x^2+3^3)^{-1}-2x(x^2+3^3)^{-2}\cdot 2=\frac{-4x}{(x^2+3^3)^2}$$

Comment: I think it's impractical to use the product or quotient rule for cases where one part of the function is a constant, because you get 'a lot' of zero-multiplications. However it's a correct and legitimate approach.

Comment: @Jasper That is a legitimate criticism. However, I think the OP will benefit from using and practicing these methods as much as possible since they are an essential part of calculus.

Comment: Shouldn't the power rule be included in the following step?

So, it's 0 times $x^2+3^3$ -2x times 3 times $x^2+3^2$ times $x^2$?

Comment: @user6050977  Remember when you have a function inside a function $(f(x))^2$ you need to differentiate the "outside" first and then the inside. So for $(f(x))^2$ we have an "outside" function "$x^2$"and an "inside" function $f(x)$. The derivative will be $2(f(x)) \cdot f'(x)$. In your case we have $(x^3+3^3)^{-1}$. The "outside" function is $x^{-1}$ and the "inside" function is $x^2+3^3$. As you rightly noticed we use the power rule for the outside function first $-1(x^2+3^3)^{-2}$ and the multiply it with the derivative of the inside function $\implies 1(x^2+3^3)^{-2} \cdot 2x$.

Answer (score 1):

Start with 3^3 = 27 so the fraction changes to 2/(x^2+27). Then you get u = 2; u' = 0; v = x^2+27; v' = 2x; The put each into: (vu'-uv')/v^2

Comment: I did write out the lines. I have nine steps written out on paper. Is this step right, at least: ${dy}/{dx}$ x 2 x ${x^2+3^3}$ - 2 x ${dy}/{dx}$  x ${x^2+3^3}$ over $({x^2+3)^6}$?

Comment: Incorporate these details into the answer, which is currently in the Low Quality review queue (and which I do believe could be improved). Rarely are "this is the answer" answers helpful.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac {d}{dx} \frac 2{(x^2+3)^3}=\frac {d}{dx} (2(x^2+3)^{-3})=2\frac {d}{dx} (x^2+3)^{-3}=2\times(-3)(x^2+3)^{-4}2x=-\frac {12x}{(x^2+3)^{4}}$$